# For Loop Ending Early - Why?

Tags: r

I have a loop that should run about 300,000 times, but it ends at 55 when I bind data to a data frame and I have no clue what is happening.

The loop in question is:

```
TrendlineMeta <- data.frame("FutureRecord" = character(), "System" = numeric(), "Intercepts" = numeric(), "Slopes" = numeric(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for (i in unique(TrendingData$FutureRecord)){
  FilteredList <- TrendingData[TrendingData$FutureRecord == i,]

  Regressed <- lm(FilteredList$Value ~ FilteredList$Time)#, na.action = na.omit)

  newrow <- c("FutureRecord"=j, "System"=max(as.character(FilteredList$System)), "Intercepts"=summary(Regressed)$coefficients[1,1], "Slopes"=summary(Regressed)$coefficients[2,1])
  TrendlineMeta <- rbind(TrendlineMeta, data.frame(as.list(newrow), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}
```

and ends after 55 itterations.

However, this loop:

```
TrendlineMeta <- data.frame("FutureRecord" = character(), "System" = numeric(), "Intercepts" = numeric(), "Slopes" = numeric(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for (i in unique(TrendingData$FutureRecord)){
  FilteredList <- TrendingData[TrendingData$FutureRecord == i,]

  Regressed <- lm(FilteredList$Value ~ FilteredList$Time)#, na.action = na.omit)

  #newrow <- c("FutureRecord"=j, "System"=max(as.character(FilteredList$System)), "Intercepts"=summary(Regressed)$coefficients[1,1], "Slopes"=summary(Regressed)$coefficients[2,1])
  #TrendlineMeta <- rbind(TrendlineMeta, data.frame(as.list(newrow), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}
```

completes fine.

What about this am I doing wrong?  I am new to R so nothing is jumping out at me.

Comment: Do not grow an object in a loop. For your task you could easily use one of the split-apply-combine functions.

Comment: Is j in "FutureRecord"=j an static object defined earlier in your code?

Comment: @Sebastian, that is supposed to be "FutureRecord"=i not j.  I had tried doing "j <- i" within the loop to see if somehow referencing i directly was messing with something.  @ Roland, I can look into that, but would growing an object within a loop cause it to end prematurely?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is just a stab at your issue, but it's a little difficult without seeing the underlying dataset.  I'm using Hadley's `purrr`, `tidyr`, `plyr` and `dplyr` packages.

It may accomplish what you're trying to do without using the loop.

```
partA <- TrendingData %>%
  split(.$FutureRecord) %>%
  map(~ lm(Value ~ Time, data = .)) %>%
  map(summary) %>%
  map("coefficients") %>% 
  map(data.frame) %>% 
  map(~ select(.x, Estimate) %>%
        mutate(coef = row.names(.))) %>%
  ldply(rbind) %>%
  rename(FutureRecord = .id) %>%
  spread(coef, Estimate)
```

From here,

```
partB <- TrendingData %>%
  select(FutureRecord, System) %>%
  group_by(FutureRecord)  %>%
  filter(System == max(System)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Then,

```
left_join(partA, partB)
```

Does that work?